# How to use python when learning algorithms?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

Basically, I am trying to learn some very basic data structures and algorithms using python. However I think when trying to implementing these algorithms, I unknowingly start using python *tricks* a bit, even as simple as the following which will not be considered tricks by any stretch of imagination

```py
for i, item in enumerate(arr):
    # Algo implementation
```

or

```py
if item in items:
    # do something
```

I don't know what is the general guideline to follow so that I can grasp the algorithm as it's meant to implemented.

Comment: The understanding of an algorithm does not depend on using some language tricks. Dijkstra's algorithm of course can be implemented with or without some language specific tricks, but the core aspect is that you understand the rationale behind it.

Comment: make the question more specific

Comment: Even if you use any trick, Just make sure you understand how that trick works. Thats all.

Answer (score 3):

It is all right to use Python's techniques to solve problems. The main exception is when Python does something for you and you want to learn *how* that something was done. One example is [Python's heapq](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/heapq.html)--You can't use that directly if your purpose is to understand how the binary heap structure can be used to implement a priority queue. Of course, you could read the source code and learn much that way.

One thing that can help you is to read a data structures and algorithms book that is based on Python. Then you can be assured that Python will not be used to slide over important topics--at least, if the book is any good.

One such book is [Problem Solving with Algorithms and Data Structures](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci105s1c/resources/ProblemSolvingwithAlgorithmsandDataStructures.pdf). Another is [Classic Computer Science Problems in Python](https://smile.amazon.com/Classic-Computer-Science-Problems-Python/dp/1617295981/ref=sr_1_1?crid=2O2XOQA57E8YT&keywords=classic+computer+science+problems+in+python&qid=1565373467&s=books&sprefix=classic+computer+s%2Caps%2C148&sr=1-1). The first book is a free PDF download, though I believe there is a more recent edition that is not free. The second is not free but you can get a discount of 40% at [the publisher's web site](https://www.manning.com/books/classic-computer-science-problems-in-python) if you use a discount code [mentioned in the Talk Python to Me podcast](https://talkpython.fm/episodes/show/211/classic-cs-problems-in-python). I am working through the latter book now, as a reminder of the class I took a very long time ago.

---

As to a recommendation, the price may be a deciding factor for you. The emphases of the two books also differs. The first is older, using more generic Python and not using many of Python's special features. It is also closer to a textbook, going more into depth in its topics. It covers things like execution complexity, for example. The PDF version, however, does not cover as many topics as other versions I have seen. The PDF does not cover graphs (networks), for example, which another version (which I cannot find now) does.

The second is much more recent, using features of Python 3.7 such as type hints. It also is more of an introduction or review. I think I can use "fair use" to quote the relevant section of the book:

> **Who is this book for?**
>
> This book is for both intermediate and experienced programmers.
>   Experienced programmers who want to deepen their knowledge of Python
>   will find comfortably familiar problems from their computer science or
>   programming education. Intermediate programmers will be introduced to
>   these classic problems in the language of their choice: Python.
>   Developers getting ready for coding interviews will likely find this
>   book to be valuable preparation material.
>
> In addition to professional programmers, students enrolled in
>   undergraduate computer science programs who have an interest in Python
>   will likely find this book helpful. It makes no attempt to be a
>   rigorous introduction to data structures and algorithms. This is not a
>   data structures and algorithms textbook. You will not find proofs or
>   extensive use of big-O notation within its pages. Instead, it is
>   positioned as an approachable, hands-on tutorial to the
>   problem-solving techniques that should be the end product of taking
>   data structure, algorithm, and artificial intelligence classes.
>
> Once again, knowledge of Python’s syntax and semantics is assumed. A
>   reader with zero programming experience will get little out of this
>   book, and a programmer with zero Python experience will almost
>   certainly struggle. In other words, Classic Computer Science Problems
>   in Python is a book for working Python programmers and computer
>   science students.

Comment: Thanks for the book recommendations. Between [Problem Solving with Algorithms and
Data Structures](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci105s1c/resources/ProblemSolvingwithAlgorithmsandDataStructures.pdf), and 
[Data Structures and Algorithms in Python](https://www.amazon.com/Structures-Algorithms-Python-Michael-Goodrich/dp/1118290275), which should I choose?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to understand how an algorithm works, I would strongly recommend to **work with [flowcharts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart)**. They represent the algorithmic procedure as relations between the elementary logical statements the algorithm is made of and are independent on the programming language an algorithm might be implemented.

If you want to learn python along with it, then here is what you can do:

#### 1. Study the flowchart of the algorithm that interests you.

#### 2. Translate that flowchart 1-to-1 into python code.

#### 3. Have a closer look at your python code and try to optimize or compact it.

---

This can be best **illustrated with an example**:

#### 1.

Here is the flowchart of Euclid's algorithm that finds the greatest common denominator of two numbers (taken form the wiki page [Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm)):

[image]

**To understand an algorithm means to be able to follow or even reproduce this flowchart**

#### 2.

Now if your goal is to learn python a great exercise is to take a flowchart and translate it to python. No shortcuts, no simplifications, just 1-to-1 as it is written, translate the algorithm to python. **You won't be fooled by any tricks or masked complexity when doing so, as the flowchart tells you the elementary logical steps and you are just translating them to your preferred programming language**.

For the example above, a crude 1-to-1 implementation looks like this:

```py
def gcd(a,b):           # point 1
    while True:
        if b == 0:      # p. 2
            return a    # p. 8 + 9
        if a > b:       # p. 3
            a = a - b   # p. 6
                        # p. 7
        else:           # p. 3
            b = b - a   # p. 4
                        # p. 5
```

#### 3.

By now you have both learned how the algorithm works and how you implement logical statements in python. The *tricks* you mentioned earlier can enter the game here. You can start to play around and try to make the implementation more efficient, more compact or a one-liner (people like this for some reason). **This will not only help your logical understanding but it will also deepen your knowledge of the programming language you are using.**

As for the example at hand, Euclid's algorithm, there is not a lot of fancy business that comes to my mind. I somehow find recursive calls elegant, so here is a *tricky* implementation using this:

```py
def gcd(a,b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    else:
         return gcd(a-b,b) if a > b else gcd(a, b - a)
```

---

*Note the you can (and sometimes even have to) do this procedure in the reverse order. It can happen that the only thing you know about an algorithm is an implementation of it. The you would proceed exactly in the reversed order: 3.->2. Try to identify and 'expand' all trickery that might be present in the implementation. 2.->1. Use the 'expanded' implementation to create a flowchart of the algorithm, in order to have a proper definition.*

Comment: I disagree with the recommendation to use flowcharts. I have found them useful only when working with a very low-level language such as machine language or for understanding someone else's poorly-written "spaghetti code." I find them useless for my own programming, so my custom is to use top-down programming with pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

They are not tricks!

These are the same thing you would do in any other language. It's just made more simpler in python.

In c/c++ you would do,

```
for(int i=0; i<sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); i++) {
     // access the array elements here as arr[i]
}
```

The same thing you would do in python in a bit convenient way i.e.

```
for i, a in enumerate (arr):
    # do something
```

or

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
     # do something with arr elements
```

Your algorithms will NOT depend upon these syntactical difference.
Whether it is in python or in c/c++ or in any other language, if you have a good understanding of the language, you are good to go with any thing. You just have to keep in mind the time complexities of the algorithms you use and how you implement them.

The thing with python is that it's way more easy to understand, it's shorter to write, has a lot of inbuilt functions, you need no class or a main function to execute your program and many more.

If you ask me, I would not say they are any tricks. All programming languages have these things in common with just syntactical difference.

It depends on what you are trying to implement. Like say if you are trying to implement linked list, you just need to know what can you use in python to implement that.